# assertion failure with message: from account is in blacklist

Tags: nodeos, wallet

While I call a contract to transfer token,I got the error like below:

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: from account is in blacklist
pending console output:
```

Anybody could help me?Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your account is blacklisted on contract-level.

Try to contact the owner, admin or developers behind the contract/token. There's nothing else you could do.